# Create an Observable that depends on a Promise

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I’m using RxJS `ajax` to create an observable for an http request that depends on a value that comes from an asynchronous source such as async storage. A non-asynchronous version is as follows:

```
export const search = term =>
  ajax(`/search?term=${term}`);
```

Later I would use this as something like:

```
fromEvent(element, 'keyup').pipe(
  switchMap(term => search(term))
);
```

This works great, however I need to update the ajax function to set an authentication token header. This token is stored in async storage. I can update the function like so:

```
export const search = async term => {
  const token = getFromStorage('token');
  return ajax(`/search?term=${term}`,
    { headers: { token } }).toPromise();
};
```

This does work, but now I need to use `fromPromise` when I want call search. This isn’t the worst thing in the world, but I’m a bit worried that I’ll lose the benefit of `switchMap` (I haven’t test that yet). It also seems like there could be a cleaner way to generate an Observable that might have an asynchronous source versus having to create a Promise.

Is there a way to generate an observable that depends on another asynchronous operation (Observable or Promise)?

Comment: Instead of tansforming the observable into a promise, transform the promise into an observable, and enjoy the switchMap operator.

Comment: I’m struggling a bit with the “transform the promise to Observable...” `fromPromise(getFromStorage('token')).pipe(switchMap(token => ajax(...)))` but then I have two switchMaps. That may be okay, but I’m also just wondering if there’s an asynchronous creation function I can use or something, or a simpler way to unwrap the nested promise.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "asynchronous creation function" (what's wrong with fromPromise()?), and by "unwrap the nested promise". Having two switchMaps is fine, too.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to use `toPromise` anyway.

Comment: @martin I may not, but I'm still returning an observable from a promise

Comment: @JBNizet nothing is wrong with `fromPromise`, it's just that if I have an asynchronous function to create the observable (asynchronous creation function) then that returns a promise that returns another promise or observable, so I have to unwrap/flatten it twice. By "unwrap the nested promise" I mean I'm returning a promise from the async function, so that's a promise that returns a promise. I believe that `switchMap` will only unwrap/flatten the outer one, so I have to have nested switchMaps.